# Joining queries and summing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following two select statements and I'm trying to ADD the result time fields together (effective time and time) to give me total --> i need to return the value of 767.35 but I just cant work out the logic. Please help!

```
SELECT [ContractID], [CostType], SUM{[Units]}as Time,[CostClass]
FROM [TGMResource].[dbo].[tblDrillOnCost]
where ContractID = '2015/023' and dataset= 'TAGOFTP17' and costclass= 'TIME' and (CostType = 'WORKING TIME' or CostType = 'SURVEY' or CostType = 'MOVE SITE'or CostType = 'TRAVEL')
GROUP BY Costtype, CostClass, DataSet, ContractID
ORDER BY CostType

SELECT SUM([DrillTime]) as Effective_Time
FROM [TGMResource].[dbo].[tblDHDrillHistory]
where ContractID = '2015/023' and dataset= 'TAGOFTP17'
GROUP BY ContractID, DataSet
```

From the first query I get the results:

```
ContractID  CostType    Time    CostClass
2015/023    MOVE SITE   35.5    TIME  
2015/023    SURVEY  27  TIME  
2015/023    WORKING TIME    44  TIME
```

from the second query i get the results

```
Effective_Time
660.85



 SELECT tblDrillOnCost.ContractID AS ContractID,
       CostType,
       SUM( Units ) + Effective_Time AS Total,
       CostClass
FROM TGMResource.dbo.tblDrillOnCost AS tblDrillOnCost
JOIN ( SELECT ContractID,
              DataSet,
              SUM( DrillTime ) AS Effective_Time
       FROM TGMResource.dbo.tblDHDrillHistory AS tblDHDrillHistory
       WHERE ContractID = '2015/023'
         AND dataset = 'TAGOFTP17'
       GROUP BY ContractID,
                DataSet
     ) AS EffectiveTimeFinder ON tblDrillOnCost.ContractID = EffectiveTimeFinder.ContractID
     WHERE CostType = 'WORKING TIME' or CostType = 'SURVEY' or CostType = 'MOVE SITE'or CostType = 'TRAVEL'
GROUP BY tblDrillOnCost.ContractID,
         Effective_Time,
         CostType,
         CostClass;
```

Gave me:

```
2015/023    MOVE SITE   696.35  TIME  
2015/023    SURVEY  687.85  TIME  
2015/023    WORKING TIME    711.85  TIME
```

which was again incorrect :(

Comment: Give some sample data, output of both of the queries and your overall expected data.

Comment: @utsav - good idea. Thank you

Comment: To improve the quality of your answer, please show us the source tables, with field names and sample data, as text within the body of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT tblDrillOnCost.ContractID AS ContractID,
       SUM( Units ) + Effective_Time AS Total
FROM TGMResource.dbo.tblDrillOnCost AS tblDrillOnCost
JOIN ( SELECT ContractID,
              DataSet,
              SUM( DrillTime ) AS Effective_Time
       FROM TGMResource.dbo.tblDHDrillHistory AS tblDHDrillHistory
       WHERE ContractID = '2015/023'
         AND dataset = 'TAGOFTP17'
       GROUP BY ContractID,
                DataSet
     ) AS EffectiveTimeFinder ON tblDrillOnCost.ContractID = EffectiveTimeFinder.ContractID
WHERE CostType = 'WORKING TIME'
   OR CostType = 'SURVEY'
   OR CostType = 'MOVE SITE'
   OR CostType = 'TRAVEL'
GROUP BY tblDrillOnCost.ContractID,
         Effective_Time;
```

This statement starts by calculating the `Effective_Time` value for that `ContractID` and `DataSet` and returning it with the `ContractID` and `DataSet` values so that the result of this subquery may be joined in the main body of the query, and because the fields used by `GROUP BY` must also be amongst those selected.

This `INNER JOIN` is performed between the subquery's result and `tblDrillOnCost` where they share the same `ContractID` value, effectively appending a copy of the `Contract`'s `Effective_Time` value to its record in `tblDrillOnCost`.

Then all that needs to be done is to select the fields.  Firstly, the `JOIN` appended *all* the fields of `EffectiveTimeFinder` to those of `tblDrillOnCost`, resulting in two fields called `ContractID` occurring in the joined dataset.  These can be differentiated between by referring to them with their source table / query name, e.g. `tblDrillOnCost.ContractID` or `EffectiveTimeFinder.ContractID`.  Only one needs to be chosen by the main body of the statement - it doesn't matter which here.  It should be given an alias here, otherwise the field name in the results will be `tblDrillOnCost.ContractID` or `EffectiveTimeFinder.ContractID` (whichever you used), which is ugly and unwieldy.

Secondly,  in addition to calculating `Time` you can also add it to `Effective_Time` in the same part of the `SELECT` statement, as with `SUM( Units ) + Effective_Time`.  If you do not give this value an alias, then the field will be given the (again ugly and unwieldy) name of `SUM( Units ) + Effective_Time`.

Thirdly, you should eliminate the fields other than `ContractID` and `Total` from the select statement.  The information you are interested in is for the `Contract` as a whole, wheras the other fields apply to subparts of the `Contract`.  Including them in a statement structured like this will force subgrouping on those fields, which will affect how `Total` is calculated.  If you want a list with `ContractID` along with each corresponding `CostType` and `CostClass` along with the *overall* total for the `Contract`, then please modify your Question to indicate this.

There is no need to add a `WHERE` filter for `ContractID = '2015/023'` to the main body of the statement since the subquery has already had this filter applied, and the `JOIN` being performed on `ContractID` will preserve this filtering effect.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: looks like ill need to add it to the group by clause. Column 'EffectiveTimeFinder.Effective_Time' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I just couldnt wrap my head around this one

Comment: Hmm added a where clause for cost type now im just getting the original "time" field added to the effective time value for each line.

Comment: Got It!! brackets and an extra constraint. Thanks for all ur help~!

Comment: No worries - glad to help.  Please note, if an Answer solves the problem presented in your Question to your satisfaction, and is deemed by you to be the most suitable Answer amongst those presented, then you may accept it as the Answer by choosing the tick next to the top of the Answer.  This rewards the Answerer with 15 points, and removes your Question from StackOverflow's list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tblDrillOnCost.ContractID AS ContractID,
       SUM( Units ) + Effective_Time AS Utilised_Time
FROM TGMResource.dbo.tblDrillOnCost AS tblDrillOnCost
JOIN ( SELECT ContractID,
              DataSet,
              SUM( DrillTime ) AS Effective_Time
       FROM TGMResource.dbo.tblDHDrillHistory AS tblDHDrillHistory
       WHERE ContractID = '2015/023'
         AND dataset = 'TAGOFTP17'
       GROUP BY ContractID,
                DataSet
     ) AS EffectiveTimeFinder ON tblDrillOnCost.ContractID = EffectiveTimeFinder.ContractID
WHERE tbldrilloncost.DataSet = 'TAGOFTP17' and tbldrilloncost.CostClass = 'time' 
AND (CostType = 'SURVEY'
   OR CostType = 'MOVE SITE'
   OR tbldrilloncost.CostType = 'TRAVEL'
   OR tbldrilloncost.CostType = 'WORKING TIME')
GROUP BY tblDrillOnCost.ContractID,
         Effective_Time;
```

Worked perfectly- Thanks for your help @toonice